# Python OpenCV 3 not reading images properly

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

In MacOS 10.11.6, I’m reading a batch of 192 *.jpg images, each of shape 160x320x3, using OpenCV 3 `cv2.imread()` from filesystem then I create a NumPy array using that batch of images. If I load it from `data01/` path (`/data01/IMG/center_2017_03_03_11_52_56_652.jpg`) then I get a return shape of:

```
X_train = np.array(read_images)
X_train.shape is (192, 160, 320, 3)
X_train[0].shape is (160, 320, 3)
```

if I read it from `data/` path (`/data/IMG/center_2016_12_01_13_41_40_419.jpg`), I get a return shape of

```
X_train.shape is (192,)
X_train[0].shape is (160, 320, 3)
```

The second case of reading from `data/` path is breaking my neural network. Any clues?

Comment: In the second case, what is `X_train.dtype`? (My guess is `dtype('O')`, i.e. an object array.)  That could happen if one of the images does not have shape 160x320, so check `X_train[k].shape` for each `k`.

Comment: Yes, you are right. In case of `data01/` the dtype is uint8, while in case of `data/` the dtype is object. The 3rd image is crashing on calculating the shape `X_train[2].shape`. On printing `X_train[2].dtype` it says `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'dtype'`. Why is that the case and what's the fix?

Comment: Take a look at `read_images[2]`.  Is it `None`?

Comment: The `type(read_images[2])` is `NoneType`. The `type(read_images[k])` is quite broken. Some of them are `numpy.ndarray` while others are `NoneType`!?!?

Comment: See my updated answer for some suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments to the question, you say that the type of some of the objects in `read_images` is `NoneType`, which means some of the values are `None`.  You'll have to fix the code that generates `read_images`, or filter out the `None` values with something like:

```
read_images = [img for img in read_images if img is not None]
```

before you execute `X_train = np.array(read_images)`.  (This assumes that the only "bad" objects in `read_images` are `None`.)

The reason the occurrences of `None` in `read_images` causes a problem is that the call to `array(read_images)` will only create a four-dimensional array if all the elements in `read_images` are "array-like" with the same shape.  If they are not, the `array()` function will instead create a one-dimensional array of Python objects.

Comment: Thanks for walking me thru it. I was building paths for the read_images and On `data/` only 1 out of every 3 paths were correctly built, the other two were adding spaces in the path, which was had os.path.isfile(path) as False.